Difference between Changelo&documenting the cleaning data process
Is there a difference between: Changelog and documenting the data cleaning process in data process cleaning?
I was learning this on the coursera google certificate and I wanted to know if it's the same or if changelog is part of documenting the data cleaning process (and if so, is there other things included in the documenting the cleaning process?)
